# Invoicing period in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports-xi, subreport

I am new to Crystal Report (version:xi). I have a Crystal Report consisting with a subreport to print the Invoicing Period. What I want to do it print the Invoicing period inside a paragraph in the Main Report. The Subreport has following codes.

Report Header: GetData

Details: @GetData

Report Footer: {@ShowData}

There are two formula fields

(1). GetData

global strPeriodBegin as string
global strPeriodEnd as string

if {REPORT_REQUEST_TMP.RRT_NAME}="INVOICING_PERIOD_BEGIN" then 
    strPeriodBegin= totext(cdate({REPORT_REQUEST_TMP.RRT_DATE}))
end if

if {REPORT_REQUEST_TMP.RRT_NAME}="INVOICING_PERIOD_END" then 
    strPeriodEnd= totext(cdate({REPORT_REQUEST_TMP.RRT_DATE}))
end if

formula = {REPORT_REQUEST_TMP.RRT_DATE}

(2). ShowData

'WhileReadingRecords
global strPeriodBegin as string
global strPeriodEnd as string
shared sh_strInvoicingPeriodHTML as string

sh_strInvoicingPeriodHTML= "**Period :** " & strPeriodBegin & " - " & strPeriodEnd

formula = strPeriodBegin & " - " & strPeriodEnd

Can anyone help me to Print this Invoicing Period inside a paragraph in Main Report.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is create a formula with a shared variable in the main report, then put that formula in the sub-report and store the value that the sub-report is returning in the shared variable that the formula has, then create another formula with that shared variable in the main report and put it in the paragraph. Notice that the formulas in the main report must be in different sections, for instance {@formula1} in the page header and {@formula2} in the report footer.